# java ArrayBlockingQueue put and take at the same time will cause deadlock?

Tags: java, concurrency

the ArrayBlockingQueue's take and put functions acting like these:

```
`final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
`
```

My question is suppose now there is no element in queue and i call take(). then the calling thread will be waiting by notEmpty.await() and at same time, the thread holds monitor of lock. if i call put() from another thread which suppose to add a new element into queue, the put() function will wait at line lock.lock() until take() calls unlock(). am i correct? if i am correct, there will be deadlock.

Comment: From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html): `"Attempts to put an element into a full queue will result in the operation blocking; attempts to take an element from an empty queue will similarly block."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the javadoc of [`Condition#await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--) states

> **The lock associated with this `Condition` is atomically released** and the
>   current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and
>   lies dormant until one of four things happens: [...]

So the `Lock` object is released and can be acquired by another thread.

Comment: what i am talking about is the lock of 
lock.lock(); and lock.unlock(), since two functions are using the same lock object. when take() gone after lock.lock() and wait there before calling lock.unlock(), the function put() will get blocked at the line lock.lock().

Comment: @tommi `notEmpty` references a `Condition` object created from that `Lock` object. When you call `await` on it, it releases that lock.